# Asociaciones en GOLANG usando GORM

Tags: go, gorm

Buen dia,

Tengo las siguientes estructuras:

```
/*
* User
 */
type User struct {
    ID              uint       `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id`
    Name            string     `json:"name"`
    Email           string     `json:"email"`
    Password        string     `json:"password"`
    JobpositionID   uint       `json:"jobposition_id"`
    CreatedAt       *time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt       *time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt       *time.Time `json:"deleted_at"`
}

/*
* Job position
 */
type Jobposition struct {
    ID          uint       `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id`
    Name        string     `gorm:"unique" json:"name"`
    Description string     `json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   *time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   *time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt   *time.Time `json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

Pero no tengo ni ideas de como hacer asociaciones en Golang usando GORM, lo que quier hacer es me me ejecute el siguiete query

```
SELECT * FROM Users u INNER JOIN Jobposition j ON j.id = u.JobpositionID
```

Agradecere cualquier tipo de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar Raw SQL(documentacion en http://doc.gorm.io/advanced.html#compose-primary-key). Dejo un ejemplo del código:

```
var result Result
db.Raw("SELECT name,email,password,jobpositionid,createdat,updatedat,deleteat FROM Users u INNER JOIN Jobposition j ON j.id = u.JobpositionID", 3).Scan(&result)
```